# C++ Program Crash on exit

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a very simple program that I don't know why a crash occurs on exit.
My main function is a simple `cout<<"Hello world";`

But I've added another cpp file:

system_information.cpp:

```
system_information::system_information() {
    threadid_processid_map[22]=23;

    processor_processid_map[128] = { 0L };
    processor_threadid_map[128] = { 0L };
}
```

And the header file looks like:

system_information.h

```
class system_information{
public:

    DWORD processor_processid_map[128];
    DWORD processor_threadid_map[128];              

    unordered_map<DWORD, DWORD> threadid_processid_map;
    system_information();
};
```

And I simply have this file to declare in instance of my class:

parse.cpp:

```
#include "system_information.h"
system_information sys_info;
```

My program crashes on exit on crt0at.c at this line:

```
onexitbegin_new = (_PVFV *) DecodePointer(__onexitbegin);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `processor_processid_map[128] = { 0L };` invokes *undefined behavior* by writing past the bounds of the array

Comment: So why does it cause a crash? Does any memory leak cause a crash?

Comment: *undefined behavior* means anything can happen - including crashes (also you don't have a memory leak in this code)

Comment: This might be a good time to learn to use your debugger.  A debug build in VS might have warned you that you'd just corrupted the stack by writing past the end of your arrays.

Comment: This is an out-of-bounds error, not a memory leak.

Comment: It might be difficult to pinpoint the problem without a debugger. My guess is that the out of bounds assignment has changed the __onexitbegin pointer. __onexitbegin and _onexitend stores the range of functions needed to be called while exiting, and the system would have crashed on calling the exitbegin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you're slightly confused about what:

```
processor_processid_map[128] = { 0L };
```

is actually doing. The fact that you have braces in there seems to indicate you think it will set all values in the array to zero but that is *not* the case. You can *initialise* the array that way but assigning to it is a different matter.

What that code is doing is trying to set element number `128` to zero and, since elements are restricted to the range `0..127`, what you have there is undefined behaviour.

If you *do* wish to zero out the entire array, there are a number of ways to do this, including:

```
// Simple loop.
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(id_map) / sizeof(*id_map); ++i)
    id_map[i] = 0;

// Setting memory.
#include <cstring>
memset(id_map, 0, sizeof(id_map));

// Fill algorithm.
#include <algorithm>
std::fill(id_map, id_map + sizeof(id_map) / sizeof(*id_map), 0);
```